# TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined

Tags: android, typescript, cordova

I am currently working on a Ionic Project. But when I try to generate a release build for Android, I get this error:

```
 Android Studio project detected
(node:13116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\restore-util.js:322:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.installPluginsFromConfigXML (C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\restore-util.js:318:28)
    at C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:59:32
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Digitalis 2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
(node:13116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13116) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I did the command: `ionic cordova build --release android` on the right folder, with all of my packages up to date.

If someone knows why I got this error (that i don't understand), and how to fix it, I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the answer, it was a problem with the plugin [cordova-barcode-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner)
. The version was too old, I had to switch to [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) and everything worked fine!